# Listing Password complexity Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

From the Google Admin panel there is a nice password strength meter and password length feature. From the admin panel go to Security >> Password Monitoring.

Is there a programatic way of getting this info exported in a report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. The Admin SDK Directory and Reports APIs do not return any information on password complexity / strength.