# Looking for threat intelligence/mitigation info from Google API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Rulerr.com is a permissions management and threat intelligence system which aggregates many sources of information into a single application for Enterprise.

I can see that we can pull activity reports on admin activities and user login info from the API, but we are looking to pull other risk profiling/threat intelligence data from GSuite API such as:

- password strength per user (not the password itself)
- when the password was last changed
- elements in the system that have been accessed by a user, and associated data (timestamps etc)

Does anyone know if it is possible to pull this data from the admin SDK API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *password strength per user (not the password itself)*

No. See [Listing Password complexity Google Admin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31148889/4625829).

> *when the password was last changed*

You have to track this yourself. I guess every [Users: update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update).

> *elements in the system that have been accessed by a user, and associated data (timestamps etc)*

Usage details that the user has can be retrieved through the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users). However, there are only [specific parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users) that you can retrieve. AFAIK, other details that are not available (like when the last password was changed) should be monitored by the developer themselves.

If you feel like this would be really useful, I would suggest that you [File a Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support#missing_features).